# StringTokenizer issues with if statements

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have to tokenize a string which looks like this:
`4830673048;Tony White`
There must be two tokens separated by a `;`
The first token must contain 10 digits, and ONLY digits
The second token may not contain digits.

```
  private static boolean isValid(String accountLine) throws BankAccountException
  {
     StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(accountLine, ";");
     boolean valid = true;
     if(strTok.countTokens() == 2)
     {
        if(strTok.nextToken().length() == 10 && strTok.nextToken().matches(".*[0-9].*"))
        {
           if(!strTok.nextToken().matches(".*[0-9].*"))
           {
              valid = true;
           }
        }
     }
     else
     {
        System.out.println("Invalid Bank Account info. " + strTok.nextToken());
        valid = false;
     }
     return valid;
  }
```

Here is the code I came up with, but it doesn't do what I expected it to do. I know the problem probably lies in my use of `.nextToken()`. So then my question is, what's the proper StringTokenizer method for ONLY checking the first or the second token?

Comment: Why are you tokenizing and then using regex? Use it on accountLine itself. Have a look at @Bohemian's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
private static boolean isValid(String accountLine) throws BankAccountException
{
   StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(accountLine, ";");
   boolean valid = true;
   if(strTok.countTokens() == 2)
   {
      String acctNum = strTok.nextToken();
      String acctHolder = strTok.nextToken();
      if(acctNum.length() == 10 
        && acctNum.matches(".*[0-9].*") 
        && !acctHolder.matches(".*[0-9].*"))
      {

        valid = true;

      }
   }
   else
   {
      System.out.println("Invalid Bank Account info. " + strTok.nextToken());
      valid = false;
   }
   return valid;
}
```

In the code you posted, you were calling `nextToken` two times while evaluating the first token, inadvertently moving on to the second token too soon.  By assigning the values to variables first, you can easily eliminate this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) with the appropriate regex and you only need one line:

```
return accountLine.matches("\\d{10};[^\\d]+");
```

Unless this is used in more than place, I would just scrap the method and use the snippet in-line.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strTok.nextToken().length() == 10 && strTok.nextToken().matches(".*[0-9].*"))
{
    if(!strTok.nextToken().matches(".*[0-9].*"))
    {
        valid = true;
    }
 }
```

Now let's look at this code. You first say `strTok.nextToken().matches(".*[0-9].*")` and than say `!strTok.nextToken().matches(".*[0-9].*")`. Just delete the inner `if` and try. You don't need a regex match for second token, so no action is needed for that.

I did some research and found [this solid example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/) from ***Mkyong*** whose tutorials I admire. In the tutorial he wrote:

```
while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(st.nextElement());
}
```

Instead of directly using `nextToken()`.

[This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) of ***Oracle*** gives more decent and all-around explanation. In that, `nextToken()` is deeply explained and exampled.

As you'll see in both examples, `nextToken()` and `nextElement()` functions both take the next token from the tokenizer. So you'll need to assign the first call of one of these functions to a variable and do controls on that. Such as:

```
String firstToken = st.nextToken().toString();
if(firstToken .length() == 10 && firstToken .matches(".*[0-9].*")) {
    ...
}
```

Don't forget to use `toString()` after `nextToken()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

private static boolean isValid(String accountLine) throws BankAccountException
  {
     StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(accountLine, ";");
     boolean valid = true;
     String bankAccount = (String)strTok.nextElement();
     if(strTok.countTokens() == 2)
     {
        if(strTok.nextToken().length() == 10 && bankAccount.matches(".*[0-9].*"))
        {
            valid = true;
        }
     }
     else
     {
        System.out.println("Invalid Bank Account info. " + bankAccount);
        valid = false;
     }
     return valid;
  }
```

Comment: This gives me "BankAccountProcessor.java:19: error: incompatible types
         String bankAccount = strTok.nextElement();
                                                ^
  required: String
  found:    Object
1 error"

http://puu.sh/2X2pO.png

Comment: Type cast it to string, code updated in resolution for the same.